# AppleScript get attribute won't return value when app is in fullscreen

Tags: applescript

This script works when terminal application(or any application) is not in FullScreen mode.  It will return the correct value of false.  When you make the application fullscreen it returns any empty value.  The only thing I can think of is that when you go fullscreen it puts it on a different desktop?  Am I missing something to activate the app differently now that it is fullscreen?

```
tell application "System Events" to set the visible of every process to true
set white_list to {"Finder", "AppleScript Editor", "Google Chrome"}

tell application "System Events"
    set process_list to the displayed name of every process whose visible is true
    set process_number to (number of items in process_list)
    set myList to process_list
end tell

repeat with theItem in myList
    if theItem is not in white_list then
        log theItem
        tell application "System Events" to tell process theItem
            set isFullScreen to the value of attribute "AXFullScreen" of windows
        end tell
    end if
end repeat
return theItem & " application is FullScreen: " & isFullScreen
```

Answer (score 1):

This line won't work as written...

```
set isFullScreen to the value of attribute "AXFullScreen" of windows
```

"windows" will return a list of windows and you can't get that attribute from a list. So you would want to write it as...

```
set isFullScreen to the value of attribute "AXFullScreen" of window 1
```

However, with that said I tried this and it seems you can't get the windows from a full screen process. The list of windows is always empty {}. So this approach of determining if an application is full screen will not work.

You'll need to think of another way to figure out if an application is full screen. I tried a couple things and couldn't find a solution. Sorry.

Comment: Thanks.  I went the window 1 approach and got the same results.  I'm looking into some methods using python as of right now.